# java multipart upload on signed amazon s3 url using php web service

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipartentity

I am working on a project which uses amazon s3 to store all the files of user.  It consists of web application and a desktop client. Desktop application is build in java. To upload a file from desktop application to amazon s3, I am requesting a web service build in php to generate a signed amazon s3 url for upload( using s3 class php ).  Desktop application uses this url to upload a file. File upload is accomplished using Multipart upload in java.  All the files are getting uploaded successfully but few extra lines are added to a file at the beginning and at the end. I am not able to figure out why these extra lines get added up

I uploaded a file a.txt whose content were “abcd” before upload. But when they are uploaded to amazon s3 using desktop java client few lines are added to it and the uploaded file looks as follows

```
 --y1IIH7wF3YYSFQ-R-Gwels7Wysmiosm91sYdNZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

abcd
--y1IIH7wF3YYSFQ-R-Gwels7Wysmiosm91sYdNZ—
```

Here is the java code

```
File file = new File("D:\\a.txt") ;
 Path source = Paths.get(file.getPath());
String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(source);
HttpPut put = new HttpPut (secretUrlFromWebServicePHP) ;
        put.setHeader("Content-Type",mimeType);
        put.setHeader("x-amz-acl","authenticated-read");
        try
        {
            MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity () ;
            ContentBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.create(mimeType)) ;
            multiPartEntity.addPart("attachment", fileBody) ;
            put.setEntity(multiPartEntity) ;
            response = client.execute(put) ;
       }
Catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

I have verified the signed url that the PHP web service is returning and it is valid. Using that signed url I have used ajax upload to amazon  s3 and it works fine. But when I upload it using multipart upload in java it add few extra lines to the file. Please can anybody suggest me anything that I am doing wrong